AWS API Gateway integration response template mapping for step functions
I have been integrating express step functions to API Gateway endpoints and have run into an issue where I am returning following object
{
  "statusCode":"500",
  "body":{
    "message: "Internal Server Error"
   }
}

OR
{
  "statusCode": "200",
  "body": {
    "result": {...}
  }
}

I want to be able to map the statusCode to HTTP status and the body to HTTP response body.
I have been able to map the statusCode to the HTTP status as follows,
##velocity template

#set($inputRoot=$input.path('$'))

#set($output=$util.parseJson($inputRoot.output))

#set($context.responseOverride.status=$output.statusCode)

this works but when I try to return the body, what I get in response (in Postman) is:
{message=Internal Server Error
}


What specific body output are you aiming to achieve? Based on the description, it seems the body already meets your requirements.

I want it in Json format. { "message": "Internal Server Error" }, as of now I am getting message=...,

Basically I want to map Body as is to Http Response Body

Can you provide some API Gateway logs?

The issue is that you have parsed the json in the template, what you want is:
##velocity template

#set($output=$input.json('$.output'))

#set($context.responseOverride.status=$input.path('$.output.statusCode')

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#input-variable-reference
The .json function of the input object will convert it to a json string istead of an object internally in VTL
